# Doesn't constraining the "auto" in C++ defeat the purpose of it?

Tags: c++, c++20, auto, c++-concepts

In C++20, we are now able to constrain the `auto` keyword to only be of a specific type. So if I had some code that looked like the following without any constraints:

```
auto something(){
  return 1;
}

int main(){
  const auto x = something();
  return x;
}
```

The variable `x` here is deduced to be an `int`. However, with the introduction of C++20, we can now constrain the `auto` to be a certain type like this:

```
std::integral auto something(){
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  const auto x = something();
  return x;
}
```

Doesn't this defeat the purpose of `auto` here? If I really need a `std::integral` datatype, couldn't I just omit the `auto` completely? Am I misunderstanding the use of `auto` completely?

Comment: `std::integral` isn't a type, it's a concept. The second version of the code is simply promising that whatever type `something()` returns, it will be a type that satisfies the concept `std::integral`.

Comment: The main purpose of that syntax is for parameters, where it’s plainly useful; return types and ordinary variables are just a bonus.

Comment: @DavisHerring I disagree with "return types and ordinary variables are just a bonus.". Here is one opinion at Reddit, https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/itxos7/comment/g5hc0v6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Comment: @CloudCho: Are you saying that constrained return (and/or variable) types are a useful middle ground between using a particular (verbose?) type and just `auto`?  I don’t disagree, but those aren’t really part of any interface.  You _could_ want to fail compilation if the return type you end up with is bad, I guess, and you could mean to document only certain properties of your return type in some cases, but that’s nothing like as powerful as the constraints on arguments.

Comment: @DavisHerring Have you thought about where the "arguments" came from? Isn't the return from other function(s) in many cases?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

A constraint on the deduced `auto` type doesn't mean it needs to be a *specific* type, it means it needs to be one of a *set* of types that satisfy the constraint. Note that a constraint and a type are not the same thing, and they're not interchangeable.

e.g. a concept like [std::integral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/integral) constrains the deduced type to be an integral type, such as `int` or `long`, but not `float`, or `std::string`.

> If I really need a `std::integral` datatype, couldn't I just omit the `auto` completely?

In principle, I suppose you could, but this would at the minimum lead to parsing difficulties. e.g. in a declaration like

```
foo f = // ...
```

is `foo` a type, or a constraint on the type?

Whereas in the current syntax, we have

```
foo auto f = // ...
```

and there's no doubt that `foo` is a constraint on the type of `f`.

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up. From what I understand, was this introduced so that the programmer sort of knows what to expect from a function that uses auto as a return type? This will surely make the code less bug-prone and easier to debug, is that correct?

Comment: @MaheeppartapSingh Yes, concepts allow the programmer to make the intent much clearer, which is always nice. There are a bunch of additional benefits, e.g. function templates that are instantiated incorrectly can be caught more easily with concepts; otherwise it would require the definition to fail, which is unpleasant (produces bad error messages, e.g.)

Comment: `auto` has given me some pretty interesting surprises over the years. Often it means I didn't get something quite right elsewhere and the additional diagnostics I could get with a constraint may catch an otherwise tricky runtime error or several pages of nigh-inscrutable template/overload resolution notes.

Comment: Iirc, earlier versions of the "concepts lite" proposal/implementation did not have the `auto` in the syntax. I believe it is mostly for there for clarity and concepts are already their own syntactical category, similar to types.

Comment: Man, I have several times thought it’d be great if my language of choice these days (TypeScript) had this feature. Nice to see I’m not alone in that!

Comment: In practice, this fills much the same purpose as including a `static_assert` check to determine whether `auto f`'s type is valid by `std::integral` rules, as would typically be done in earlier language versions.  It's similar to constraining template parameters to a specific interface in, e.g., Java or C#.

Comment: "[...] the syntax [without auto] was rejected from standardization, because you can’t tell whether this is a function template or a regular function without knowing whether animal is a type or a concept."
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/abbreviated-function-templates-and-constrained-auto/

Answer (score 37):

> If I really need a `std::integral` datatype, couldn't I just omit the auto completely?

No, because [`std::integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/integral) is not a type, it's a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), a constraint on types (or if you will, a set of types rather than a single type).

> Doesn't this defeat the purpose of auto here?

The original purpose of `auto` in C++11 is telling the compiler: **Whatever type you deduce**.<sup>*</sup>

With C++20, `auto` has an expanded use case - together with a concept, a constraint over types. `auto` *still* tells the compiler: **Whatever type you deduce** - but the deduction must also respect the constraint.

<sub>* - ignoring issues like constness, l/rvalue reference etc.</sub>

Comment: It's interesting that _constraining_ gives _more_ (or expanded) use cases. But I agree: constraining gives _more_ power because it gives more _guarantees_. :-)

Comment: @PabloH: Similar to the principle of Inheritance in Object Oriented Design. The “sub”-class has potentially more functionality than the parent or “super”-class.

Comment: Re *The original purpose of auto is telling the compiler: Whatever type you deduce.* The original purpose of auto was to tell the compiler that an object had automatic storage (as opposed to `register` or `static` or `extern`). The `auto` keyword was rarely used because that was the default for variables at block scope. There was no reason to use `auto SomeType foo` when `SomeType foo` meant the same thing. This was what made it so easy to usurp the `auto` keyword in C++11 for other purposes.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Edited to clarify we're talking about C++11-auto, not the earlier use of the keyword which is not related to this question.

Answer (score 5):

A concept often just move the error earlier in the compilation and makes code a bit more readable (since the concept name is a hint to the reader what you require from a type).

Rephrased:

**It is rare you will ever use an auto variable in a way that it will work on every type.**

For example:

```
auto fn(auto x) {
    return x++;
}
```

will not work if you do:

```
f(std::string("hello"));
```

because you can not increment `std::string`, the error is something like:

```
error: cannot increment value of type 'std::basic_string<char>'
    return x++;
```

If you change the function to:

```
auto fn(std::integral auto x) {
    return x++;
}
```

You will get an error like:

> :6:6: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not
> satisfied [with x:auto = std::basic_string] auto
> fn(std::integral auto x) {

For a small example this, it does not matter a lot, but for real code often the fn would call fn2 that calls fn3...  and you would get the error deep in the std/boost/... implementation file.

So in this way concepts move the error to the site of the first function call.